# MapForce skipping hierarchically-nested elements?

Tags: edi, x12, map-force

I'm creating a mapping from the X12 5010 837 format to XML using MapForce 2013 and the EDI config they provide for this format. My XML schema is hierarchical, e.g.:

```
Provider > Patient > Claim > Diagnoses, Procedures, Revenues, Payers
```

The mapping is configured to:

1. create a new Provider every time a hierarchical loop with a level code of 20 is found, and
2. create a new Patient every time a hierarchical loop with a level code of 22 is found.

I end up with the correct number of providers with this configuration. However, I end up with nothing inside of a the providers. When I remove the connection mentioned above (#1), I then get a single provider with all of the patients inside of it.

The file I'm testing with has a bunch of providers, each with a single patient.

So, it seems that by connecting the hierarchical provider loop to my Provider element, it is skipping all child loops/elements.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: ...what am I doing wrong; why is MapForce skipping nested elements?